# style option tag for jquery-ui autocomplete solution - appear as vertical list

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

[image]

Screenshot of autocomplete lumping all results together in one line as opposed to as a vertical list.

**I have the below:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      if(this.element.is("select")) {
        var self = this;
        this.original = this.element.hide();
        this.element = $("<input/>").insertAfter(this.original);
        this.options.source = function(request, response) {
          var filter = $.ui.autocomplete.filter,
            $options = self.original.find("option"),
            result = $options.map(function() {
              return $(this).val();
            });
          response(filter(result, request.term));
        };
      }
      this._super("_create");
    },
    _destroy: function() {
      this._super("_destroy");
      this.element.remove();
      this.original.show();
    }
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete();
  });
});
```

In accordance with my mark up, which looks like:

```
<select id="autocomplete">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
```

It is showing the auto complete options on one line currently; ie. Type in A, the results are '`ALAKAR...`' etc all on one horizontal line -- I would like this to appear as.

*ie.* Alabama
    Alaska
    Etc
    Etc

I don't want to alter the HTML mark-up. I have tried styling the option tag as follows.

*ie.*

```
option { 
  float:left;
  width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using `<option>` tags as a *source* of data for jquery autocomplete, but this is not the same element that you are seeing in your filtered results. The actual element being generated/displayed is likely a list item or `li` (at least it is in all the demo examples).

[Edited] Originally I thought the OP needed to style the `<option>` tags directly

Comment: This didn't work. option { display: block !important; } Thank you, though.

Comment: On second thought, we're not really interested in the `<option>` tags at all. Are you using the  jQuery UI CSS framework?

Comment: Your not really interested in the option tag? Oh, well - I would like to solve this while using option tag.

Comment: You are assuming that the `option` tags are what need to be styled, but the `options` are just a *source* of data for the widget. Trying styling the list items (the actual element being generated/displayed by the widget).

Comment: Thanks -- why would you suggest this? I tried #selector ul li { float:left; } and select ul li { float: left; } Did not work.